# How to get a child element innerhtml using the parent classname in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I have an HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
   <span class="child">Child elements</span>
</div>
```

code:

```
Ext.query('.parent'); //give me
```

o/p:

```
<div class="parent"><span class="child">Child elements</span></div>
```

how do I get access to the child element so that I can update the child text value?

Comment: I would suggest you provide some more context. Can you bound the query, or do you need to search all nodes in the document?

Comment: AWesome guys!!! Thanks for all the responses...works now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One not very elegant way of solving this can be:

```
Ext.query('.parent')[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML  = 'Your text here';
```

When you use `Ext.query ('.parent')`, you get an array of all children objects [`(DOM)`](https://www.w3.org/2002/07/26-dom-article.html) of the objects that have `parent` class. In this case, only one *item* will be returned in the array. This *item* is the `div` whose class is `parent`.

This *item* has three children, `#text`, `span` and `#text` again. The first `#text` refers to the text that is before `span`, the `span` that is our target object, and the third object is `#text`, which is the text that lies after the `span`.

So you need to access the second element of the array, which in this case is `span`. Then just access the `innerHTML` property and set the text.

[Here fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r2p), check the `index.html` file in the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.query('.parent span.child')[0].innerHTML  = 'Your new child text';
```

The query `.parent span.child` matches all spans with the class `child` in the `parent` div.
`Ext.query` returns an array of DOM objects, which you can manipulate.

If you need objects of `Ext.dom.Element` you can call the query function with `true` as it's secound parameter. See the [documentation of ExtJs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.html#method-query) for more informations.

[A working fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r3q)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way: using setText [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r3r)